# argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "segment*" - Why won't it accept the object?

Tags: c, parameters

I am attempting to initialise an array to store segments of a snake for a snake game

the structure of the type 'segment' is defined here

```
 typedef struct snakeSegment {
    int x,y;
    }segment
```

Then I declare the structure of the snake (made up by segments)

```
struct snakeSegment snake[200];
```

The following code is the initialisation of the snake array

```
/*****************************************/
/* Create snake array of length snake_length */
void initSnake(segment snake[], int snake_length)
{
  int x = 50;
  int y = 50;
  snake[0].x= x;
  snake[0].y= y;
   for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++ ) 
  {
    snake[i].x= snake[i-1].x;
    snake[i].y= snake[i-1].y;
    x++;
  }
}
```

It reaches a problem whenever it gets to the main method and trys to run the initSnake() function

here is the main function

```
int main() { 
  initDevices();
  remainingSnakes = initGame();
  while ( remainingSnakes ) {
   // waitForStart();
    snakeInPlay= 1;
    currentDirection= 'N';
    initSnake(snake_length, snake );
    renderSnake(snake_length);
  }}
```

On the initSnake() line of code, it produces this error upon compiling:
of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "segment *"

I've asked around my peers and some seem to be having this issue. We would look for an alternative soloution but we were provided with a main function that was not to be greatly altered.
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated as I have no idea why I'm recieving this error. Thanks!

here is the main function we are meant to use to model against:

```
initialiseDevices();
remainingSnakes= initialiseGame();
while ( remainingSnakes ) {
waitForStart();
snakeInPlay= 1;
currentDirection= N;
snakeLength= 10;
initialiseSnake( snake, snakeLength );
renderSnake( snake, snakeLength );
while ( snakeInPlay ) {
newDirection= ReadBoardAngle();
currentDirection= moveSnake ( snake, newDirection, snakeLength );
snakeInPlay= testSnakeCollision( snake, snakeLength );
delay();
}
}
```

Comment: It appears the arguments to `initSnake()` are in the wrong order.

Comment: *'ve asked around my peers and some seem to be having this issue.* You asked multiple people and nobody spotted this ?

Comment: Can you tell we're cramming a semester's work? Haven't had much C experience. I was unaware that the order of them would cause any issues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This aren't the parameters your function takes: `initSnake(snake_length, snake );`

You probably meant `initSnake(snake, snake_length);`

Comment: This was the problem, I'm a spanner

Answer (score 3):

The way you have it written, the arguments `snake` and `snake_length` are reversed, so you are trying to pass an int where it is expecting a snake*.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the arguments in wrong order.

Your method signature is:

```
void initSnake(segment snake[], int snake_length)
```

You are passing:

```
 initSnake(snake_length, snake );
```

You are passing the `int` value as first parameter instead of `segment` array

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you switched the parameters to initSnake between defining the function and calling it.